# Does convergence in distribution of discrete random variables with same finite support imply convergence in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let ${X_m}\mathop  \to \limits^D Y$ and ${\text{supp}}\left( {{X_m}} \right) = {\text{supp}}\left( Y \right) = \left\{ {0,1, \ldots ,n} \right\},\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$. Does ${X_m}\mathop  \to \limits^\mathbb{P} Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not--try $X_n=X_1$ for every $n$ with $X_1$ uniform on $\{0,2\}$, and $Y=2-X_1$. Then:

- $X_n$ converges to $Y$ in distribution since $X_n\stackrel{d}{=}Y$ for every $n$
- $X_n$ does not converge to $Y$ in probability since $P(|X_n-Y|\geqslant1)$ does not converge to $0$ since $|X_n-Y|=2$ almost surely hence $P(|X_n-Y|\geqslant1)=1$ for every $n$